# Namespace for OData libraries v4 vs v4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, reference, nuget

I need to change the .NET framework of an existing solution from 4.5.1 to 4.0.

Several of the projects in the solution reference OData.

I have updated the references (luckilly NuGet is used here) but it seems like the namespaces are different, or I've made a glaring error somewhere.

I get the following errors when I try a build:

```
The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

This is a typical reference list:

```
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;
```

No amount of changing references seems to help, so I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the reason:

http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/using-web-services/asp.net-web-api/developer-guide-wcfservices-web-api-install-nuget-netframework40